# Make bootstrap column content fixed positioned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-position

I have a bootstrap row with two columns and some offset. I want the last column to be `fixed` positioned so that It can be viewed while scrolling too. The last column has image content in it.

I used `affix` class which comes with bootstrap to position a div in the last column as fixed. But it resizes/overflows the image in the last column.

You can check these jsfiddles to get the idea of what I'm talking about:

1. Without fixed position/`.affix`: https://jsfiddle.net/tpw9n2e7/1/
2. With fixed poisition/`.affix`: https://jsfiddle.net/tpw9n2e7/2/

How do I make the div fixed without resizing or overflowing contents in the child div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `.affix` div will not follow the above div `col-md-4` since its position is fixed.

You must add a class of the parent div into the `.affix` class so the child content will follow the `.affix`.

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="affix col-sm-4">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x750" class="img-responsive"/>
     <br/>
     Fixed Content
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the job. Care to explain how it works?

Comment: You're welcome bro. I'm not sure but by adding the same width as the parent which is col-sm-4 to the fixed div should make the fixed div has the same width as its parent div. It's also possible to add width:inherit to the fixed div but I see there is about high difference in the width, so instead of that using the same class as the parent which define the width  should be better.